# 2 single digit lottery game, can't find where I went wrong

Tags: java

I am trying to design a lottery game where you choose 2 single digit numbers and they are compared to random numbers. I am going off of a code example given to me by my professor and have tried to tweak it to use it. I am stuck in figuring out how to get it to run or what I have wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lottery {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lottery = "" + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        String lottery1 = "" + (int) (Math.random() * 10);

        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your first single digit guess: ");
        String guess = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your second single digit guess: ");
        String guess1 = input.nextLine();

        int lotteryDigit1 = lottery.charAt(0);
        int lottery1Digit1 = lottery.charAt(1);

        int guessDigit1 = guess.charAt(0);
        int guess1Digit1 = guess1.charAt(1);

        System.out.println("The lottery number is " + lottery);

        if (guess.equals(lottery))
            System.out.println("Exact match: you win $10,000");
        else if (guess1Digit1 == lotteryDigit1
                && guessDigit1 == lottery1Digit1)
            System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $3,000");
        else if (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
                || guessDigit1 == lottery1Digit1
                || guess1Digit1 == lotteryDigit1
                || guess1Digit1 == lottery1Digit1)
            System.out.println("Match one digit: you win $1,000");
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, no matches");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is with all this conversion? You are using `String` `char` and `int` - just use `int`

Comment: I am just going off of the example i was given and trying to tweak it to make it work for what i want it to do.

Comment: Hint: Scanner has a `nextInt` method.  Get rid of all but `int`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are suggesting, sorry but I'm still pretty new to JAVA

Comment: See my answer Adam, which I think simplifies your code somewhat

Answer (score 0):

I can only call this method of handling the functions of this program "interesting".  Nonetheless, you need to add the following changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lottery {

   private static Scanner input;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String lottery = "" + ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) + ((int) (Math.random() * 10));

      input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter your two digit guess: ");
      String guess = input.nextLine();

      int lotteryDigit1 = lottery.charAt(0);
      int lottery1Digit1 = lottery.charAt(1);

      int guessDigit1 = guess.charAt(0);
      int guess1Digit1 = guess.charAt(1);

      System.out.println("The lottery number is " + lottery);

      if (guess.equals(lottery))
         System.out.println("Exact match: you win $10,000");
      else if (guess1Digit1 == lotteryDigit1
             && guessDigit1 == lottery1Digit1)
         System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $3,000");
      else if (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
           || guessDigit1 == lottery1Digit1
           || guess1Digit1 == lotteryDigit1
           || guess1Digit1 == lottery1Digit1)
         System.out.println("Match one digit: you win $1,000");
      else
         System.out.println("Sorry, no matches");
   }
}
```

The issue with the original program is that it forgot to condense lottery and lottery1 into lottery, which I added, and it opted to take the digits separately, which was highly inefficient.  Now, both are two digit numbers, and the rest of the system stays intact.  The code is now simplified for its purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code which is rather simplified

```
    // uses java.util.Random
    Random rand = new Random ();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int guess1 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int guess2 = rand.nextInt(10);

    System.out.println("Enter number 1");
    int myGuess1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number 2");
    int myGuess2 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("Random1 %d Random2 %d Guess1 %d Guess2 %d", 
                                      guess1, guess2, myGuess1, myGuess2);
```

**I will leave the comparison to you**